# AsyncSocket startTLS : CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) on iOS8.0

Tags: ios, ssl, asyncsocket, starttls

My app using a self-signed ssl certificate to connect to tcp server. It worked before iOS7.1, after iOS8.0,it has a problem when off net weight, suggesting : CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) and can not reconnect.

i am using the method:startTLS for setting the ssl, the code like below:

```
// Configure SSL/TLS settings

NSMutableDictionary *sslSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSData *pkcs12data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:certificate ofType:@"p12"]];

CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (CFDataRef)CFBridgingRetain(pkcs12data);

CFStringRef password = CFSTR("123456");

const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };

const void *values[] = { password };

CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);

OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, options, &items);

CFRelease(options);

CFRelease(password);

[pkcs12data release];

if(securityError == errSecSuccess) {

    NSLog(@"Success opening p12 certificate.");

}

CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);

SecIdentityRef myIdent = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict,
                                                              kSecImportItemIdentity);

SecIdentityRef  certArray[1] = { myIdent };

CFArrayRef myCerts = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)certArray, 1, NULL);

[sslSettings setObject:(id)CFBridgingRelease(myCerts) forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLCertificates];

[sslSettings setObject:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv2 forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLLevel];

[sslSettings setObject:(id)kCFBooleanFalse forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain];
```

Comment: could you please let me know how you have fixed the issue.